# What are the subspaces in $P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let L be the sum of certain subspaces$M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_n(n>2)$ and show that L is the direct sum of these subspaces if and only if  each $M_{i}$ is disjoint from the subspace spanned by all other.This part is proved.

Show that the converse of this statement is false by exhibiting 
three subspaces $M_1,M_2,M_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$M_1 \cap M_2=M_1 \cap M_3=M_2 \cap M_3=\{0\}$$

and $M_1 \cap (M_2+M_3)\neq \{0\}$

I tried that in$\mathbb{R}^3$

$$M_1=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb \mid x+y+z=0\}$$

$$M_2=\{x=z=0\}$$

$$M_3=\{x=y=0\}$$

So, i got the example in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Now,

Is it possible to find this type of example in $P_2$(polynomials having $\leq 2$ degree over $\mathbb{R}$) ?

I tried that

$$M_1=\{a+bx\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

$$M_2=\{cx^2\mid c \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
What will be the $M_3$? or if any other three subspaces are there then also tell me.
satisfying above criteria.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, 
You can identify $a+bx+cx^2$ with $(a,b,c)$ . I didn't check your example, but, if it's right, 
then you can take the same example:

$M_1=\{a+bx+cx^2;(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3, a+b+c=0 \}$

$M_2=\{0+bx+0x^2;(0,b,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$

$M_3=\{0+0x+cx^2;(0,0,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$

You can identify $a+bx+cx^2$ with $(a,b,c)$

Comment: Is it span of $M_2$ and $M_3$ whole  $P_2$?

Comment: Can u tell me atleat one polynomial in $M_1 \cap (M_2+M_3)$?

Comment: i got is whenever $c=-b$ those poly. will be in above intersection(namely $x-x^2$ where b=1 and c=-1 ) Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: oh thanks.your name is too typical to wright please edit.

Comment: haha,I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As vector spaces, $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $P_2$ are isomorphic, because they have the same dimension.  See if you can translate your example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to one in $P_2$.